# Why does Maven clean remove my codes that I have coded?

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, maven-clean-plugin, appian

Background: I am using an appian-plugin where Java is the main language to do customizations.

I have inserted codes into a class that belongs to the plugin working space and whenever I maven clean install, at the clean process, my codes will be gone. I heard from other colleagues that it could be because of a .wsdl file that automatically generates files when it's redeployed?
Kindly do advise. Thank you.

This is the extract of code that I'm trying to insert.

```
public static Comparator <DummyFormData> sortWageIncrementFinancialYr = new Comparator <Dummy>() {
        public int compare(DummyFormData u1, DummyFormData u2) {
            int compare1 = u1.financialYr.get(0);
            int compare2 = u2.financialYr.get(0);
            
            Boolean result = compare1 > compare2;
            return result  ? 1 : -1;
        }
        
    };
```

.wsdl codes relating to this

```
 <xs:complexType name="DummyFormData">
                <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="financialYr" type="xs:int" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="totalWagesOfWorkers" type="xs:decimal" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element name="numOfWorkers" type="xs:int" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                 </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: is your code part of target folder?

Comment: @sanjeevRm hi yes it is! just checked

Comment: probably the class you are modifying is auto generated based on the wsdl, so it gets overwritten on every deploy. easiest approach would be to put your code in a class that is not generated automatically

Comment: mvn clean will delete target folder, but it should be generated once you run **mvn install**

Comment: @LazarPetrovic is there a way to ensure that this extract of codes get written automatically as well? Because comparator collections.sort require me to code it in this class!

Comment: @sanjeevRm yes install works to compile the jar . but I'm worried that when it shifts up the development repo to higher environments, whenever it compiles, it'll erase the code and 'screw' the system

Comment: @LazarPetrovic maybe one way is to write into the wsdl to include the extract of code I have written?

Comment: Do your think that this input into wsdl will work??? I'm not sure the type is "xs:int"
<xs:element name="sortWageIncrementFinancialYr" type="xs:int" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

Comment: @MarcusMoo you can supply any comparator to sort `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`. This is the easiest way in my opinion, that way you don't have to deal with the lib that generates code from the wsdl

Comment: FWIW, your Comparator is incorrect for "equals" case. Just use `Integer.compare(int,int)`